# People content varies from Contacts

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have Outlook 2013 as one of my work installed applications.

I have two issues with my `People` and my `Contacts` list (that is available under *Address Book*)

1. The two lists have differences, even after I deleted all the content under `People`(which also cleansed `Contacts`) and started again. I presume these lists should always be the same?
2. I am also unable to add the details of particular people from the GAL by the normal methods I use (but most people do work).

   - right clicking a person in an address field and selecting *Add to Outlook Contacts*.
   - right clicking a person in the Address Book in the GAL, and selecting *Add to Contacts*.

I would like to provide more details, but there isn't anything else I can think of other than my Outlook Connectivity settings below.

[image]